# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. using ParseExact on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse a string to a date using "en-CA" culture info.
It works fine on Windows Server 2008 R2 but shows exception in Windows Server 2012 :-
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Below is the code segment :-

```
 DateTime tvDefaultDate = DateTime.ParseExact("31/12/9999", "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                                                      new CultureInfo("en-CA"));
```

Comment: Your code works in .NET 4.5 version. Which .net framework version you using in your Windows Server 2012 machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` here simply represents "date separator" (`DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator`), in the same way that with numbers `,` represents "thousands separator" (not comma), and `.` represents "decimal separator" (not period).

In en-CA, the separator character is mapped to `-`; the date would need to be `31-12-9999`. To use the literal `/` rather than the date separator, you need to escape it:

```
DateTime tvDefaultDate = DateTime.ParseExact("31/12/9999", @"dd\/MM\/yyyy",
        new CultureInfo("en-CA"));
```

Alternatively, use the invariant culture instead; the invariant culture uses `/` for the date separator.

Comment: user1315023 wrote that his code is working perfect in windows server 2008R2, but have problem in windows server 2012, can you give reason of that too ?

Comment: @Jageen presumably the en-CA culture info is configured slightly differently between OS versions; I would guess that it was simply incorrect in server 2008R2, and has been updated in 2012. I also wouldn't rule out registry tweaks on the old server (you can, IIRC, tweak cultures via the registry)

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell, the change suggested by you works fine even with the Culture Info provided...

Comment: Which .NET Framework version you used on this code Marc? Because in 4.5 framework, `(new CultureInfo("en-CA")).DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator` returns `/` not `-`. In [ideone](http://ideone.com/yiONwN) either.

Answer (score 0):

The culture is not needed in the `IFormatProvider`, simply pass `null`.

```
DateTime tvDefaultDate = DateTime.ParseExact("31/12/9999", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(tvDefaultDate);
```

Outputs:

```
12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM
```

(Sorry for the US formatting of the final date.)

Comment: But what if he wants to specify a culture? Apparently, he does want that.

Comment: AI agree with usr. I don't believe that the `IFormatProvider` is not needed.

Comment: The reason the provided culture info didn't work, is because `CultureInfo("en-CA").DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator` is `-`, not `/`, so if the user wants to use the format provided, they must escape the `/` or use `-`. Hence, null IS a viable solution for the specified use case.

Comment: @PeteGarafano null is one of several viable solutions; which of those is correct depends a lot on the intent; frankly, I'd rather see `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` than `null`

Comment: @MarcGravell there are lots of solutions to every problem.

Comment: @MarcGravell you are correct, `InvariantCulture` is better, updated.

Comment: @Pete ooh, actually: I would say that `null` is actively harmful - it becomes "current", which means it depends on a whole bunch of things, including installation locale and the current thread; yeah, I would **much** rather see `InvariantCulture` there

Comment: @MarcGravell in fact, null is *not* viable because on a Canadian machine the code will stop working. Looks like InvariantCulture is the right choice. Update: Your last comment says just that.

Comment: @MarcGravell you are correct (took me a few to dig through mscorlib) but it defaults to the current thread culture is null is passed. Which is why it worked for me, my thread culture is "en-US". `InvariantCulture` is the appropriate parameter to pass.

Comment: @PeteGarafano yeah, it is tucked away in the last line of `GetInstance` - wasn't obvious to me either, until I looked in reflector.