# .NET - Canadian DateTime Format Bug

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, culture

I currently have an application that needs to support multiple cultures.  A date string is being passed in and is being parsed to a DateTime object.  To allow for multiple cultures I am first setting the thread's culture and UICulture.

Here is an example of my code as it is:

First I set the culture for this thread.  This is passed in on the URL (ex. en-us, en-ca, fr-ca):

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(culture, false);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

I then take a date string that is also passed in on the URL and convert it to a DateTime.  Depending on the culture the date will be passed in as mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy.

I parse the date strings with the following code:

```
DateTime DateTimeObject;
bool validDate = DateTime.TryParse(DateStringFromURL, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTimeObject);
```

The TryParse works for most cultures and out comes a valid datetime object.  A problem arises with en-ca and fr-ca though.  If the wrong format is passed in, the datestring does not parse correctly.

The following shows which format .NET seems to expect for each culture:

```
         dd/MM/yyyy    MM/dd/yyyy
EN-CA      Valid        Invalid
FR-CA     Invalid        Valid
```

EDIT:
To be more exact here are the examples causing me problems:

For EN-CA:

```
DateTime.Parse("26/08/2014") //VALID
DateTime.Parse("08/26/2014") //EXCEPTION THROWN
```

For FR-CA:

```
DateTime.Parse("26/08/2014") //EXCEPTION THROWN
DateTime.Parse("08/26/2014") //VALID
```

This is backwards from how other systems treat this culture's date formatting.

Why are the formats seemingly backwards?
Is this a bug with .NET 4.5?

Any and all help would be appreciated, thanks.

NOTE:  .NET Version 4.5

Comment: Do you have a sample date string which is failing for Canadian culture with `DateTime.TryParse` ?, Can use use `DateTime.TryParseExact` with a specific format or group of pre-defined formats. One more thing, lower case `mm` is for minutes, for month it is upper case `MM`

Comment: Can you post the exact strings which produces the problem? It works as expected for me.

Comment: Your assumptions do not jive well with either .NET or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Canada).

Comment: @Hans:  That could very well be the case.  However there is some merit to my assumptions. From the wikipedia article you link to:

"European dd/mm/(yy)yy (e.g., 31/12/(20)09) date format is still widely known, especially in Quebec because it is the order used when a date is spoken in French (e.g., trente et un décembre deux mille neuf). The MM/dd/(yy)yy (e.g., Dec 31, (20)09) date format, with the month specified by name, is also common because of the influences from the United States, and because of the way Canadians say dates in English (e.g., "January 1st, 2014)."

Comment: Your examples don't match your Invalid/Valid grid.

Comment: You should probably look into Invariant culture.  That is what you should use for your URL passing.  You can use the local culture for DISPLAY purposes on the client.

Comment: @Hans:  You are correct.  I mixed up the valid/invalid.  I will fix this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably look into `Invariant` culture. That is what you should use for your URL passing. You can use the local culture for *display* purposes on the client.

Typically, whenever you are storing data (for example, in a database or file ) it is best to use the Invariant culture.  When displaying data you can use the local culture.  When passing data around, you want to use Invariant culture.

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I am quickly coming to that realization.  I think this is the path I will end up taking.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your assumptions are wrong. This console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var enca = new CultureInfo("en-ca", false);
    var frca = new CultureInfo("fr-ca", false);

    Console.WriteLine("enca dd/MM/yyyy: " + ParseDate("26/08/2014", enca));
    Console.WriteLine("enca MM/dd/yyyy: " + ParseDate("08/26/2014", enca));

    Console.WriteLine("frca dd/MM/yyyy: " + ParseDate("26/08/2014", frca));
    Console.WriteLine("frca MM/dd/yyyy: " + ParseDate("08/26/2014", frca));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static bool ParseDate(string date, CultureInfo culture)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime.Parse(date, culture);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Has output:

```
enca dd/MM/yyyy: False
enca MM/dd/yyyy: True
frca dd/MM/yyyy: False
frca MM/dd/yyyy: True
```

Comment: That is curious.  For FR-CA, those are the results I am getting.  For EN-CA the opposite is occurring, only "MM/dd/yyyy" is valid.

I am getting these results in both running my application and stopping at a breakpoint and passing in different values in the immediate window.  I will try reproducing your results.

Thanks.

Comment: I just ran that exact code.  My results differed from yours.  FR-CA matched, EN-CA was the opposite.

Comment: @EthanTowne what version of .NET? 4.5 here.

Comment: .NET 4.5 here as well.

Comment: Very odd indeed. I'd go InvariantCulture as mentioned in the accepted answer, and display it as you please using local cultures. At least that way your parsing won't be a nightmare.

Comment: is it possible that this depends on the specific settings you have for date format on your computer? did you override the default for your set culture? edit: ah, i just realise that the boolean argument should prevent that.

Comment: I wonder if the difference @EthanTowne and Haney are seeing has some relation to the problem asked about in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887521/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-using-parseexact-on-windows-serve..

Answer (score 2):

There is definitely a bug in data parsing for Canadian culture. If you try following having CurrentCulture = "en-CA":

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2014/09/20", "yyyy/MM/dd", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture)
```

you'll get following exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

works fine if you replace **/** with something else, like **-** or with InvariantCulture.